# allowed cTypes in backenlayouts / gridelements not working anymore in TYPO3 7.6?

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

TYPO3 7.6.4
I have several backendlayouts and also one gridelement for 2col.
Now I limit the available cTypes for each column like this:
(just an example)

```
mod {
web_layout {
    BackendLayouts {
        Home {
            title = Home
            config {
                backend_layout {
                    colCount = 1
                    rowCount = 3
                    rows {
                        1 {
                            columns {
                                1 {
                                    name = Slider
                                    colPos = 1
                                    colspan = 1
                                    allowed = custom_slider
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        2 {
                            columns {
                                1 {
                                    name = Content
                                    colPos = 0
                                    colspan = 1
                                    allowed = header, html, shortcut
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            icon = icon/path
        }
```

...

For the columns slider it works just fine.
FOr column content the NewContentWizard shows this 3 Elements, but when I add one, the only element that is allowed (listed in the cType dropdown) is "header" - in that case - so in general its the first cType from allowed.

Does anyone can reproduce or now what's the problem? Otherwise it could be a bug and I'll report it.

Thanks for any feedback or solution!

Kind regards
Tobi

Comment: I created a Bug-Report for that https://forge.typo3.org/issues/75248 - will keep you up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I put whitespaces into the list...
so changing

```
allowed = header, html, shortcut
```

into

```
allowed = header,html,shortcut
```

works like expacted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a compact way to manage the "New Content Element Wizard" via the core / Page TSConfig:

```
// remove everything
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common.show =
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.special.show =
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.forms.show =
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.plugins.show =
// add additional tabs like mask if available    

// add specific - by colPos and backend_layout (if needed)
[globalVar = GP:colPos==0]&&[page|backend_layout = 0]
  mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common.show := addToList(header)
[end]
```

Comment: The backend layout condition doesn't seem to slide up the tree though

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this code, which only keeps the selected items. This also removes plugins and items in other tabs

```
[globalVar = GP:colPos==0]&&[page|backend_layout = 0]
    TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.keepItems := addToList(header)
[end]
```